# How do I change which pickup a specific Guitar Pro 7.5 track uses?

Tags: guitar, pick-ups, transcription, guitar-pro

I have a guitar part which uses the neck pickup. How do I switch the track to neck pickup so that it sounds more like the original track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following numbers correspond to different segments in the below screenshot:

1. Open the track editor (in the right-hand sidebar, shortcut: F6)
2. Expand the sound details ("Show/hide sound details" tooltip)
3. Click "Bank settings" (the headstock image)
4. Change the pickup using the "Position" dropdown menu

[image: Screenshot of the track editor menu, with labels corresponding to each step in the instructions]